# Using uninitialized memory for variable ans

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to solve a problem from the CodeForces. The problem name is Sereja and Dima. I have a written code that keeps giving me 2 errors. 1st one is using uninitialized memory ans. 2nd is using uninitialized memory ans[ BYTE:0]. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. Any kind of help or suggestions would be appreciated. I am sharing my code here.

```
// Code by Neel Mehta 
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n; cin >> n;
    int ans[2];
    int num[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> num[i];
    }

    int l = 0;
    int r = n - 1;
    int f = 1;

    while (l <= r) {
        ans[f] += max(num[l], num[r]);
        if (num[l] > num[r]) {
            l++;
        }
        else {
            r++;
        }
        f ^= 1;// 0001
               // 0001
               // 0000
    }

    cout << ans[1] << " " << ans[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't initializing the memory for this variable here: `int ans[2];` so it can contain anything. When you use it here `ans[f] += max(num[l], num[r]);` you never know what you'll get because you didn't start with a known initialized value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler already told you what to do. What value are you supposing to be in ans If you haven't intialized It? Do you expect It to be 0? Then initialize: `int ans[2] = {0};` or use vector that already initializes to 0 by default: `vector<int> ans(2);`

Remember that `x += y;` is equivalent to `x = x + y;` and, If that the first place that `x` is being assigned to, then the result is unpredictable! (Unless `x` happen to be global or static, which then would imply in an initialization to 0).

Comment: Now, the code does not show any error but It's not producing or/and show output. May you assist me regarding this.

Comment: I don't know what your code is supposed to do... But I'm guessing that maybe your `r++` should be `r--`